# Manual Template Matching using Normalized Cross Correlation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

So, I have to code a template matching code using this 
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP6RH.png).

This is how my function looks like, how do I make this work? It´s going to return a value between 1 and 0, right?

```
import numpy as np

def correlation(image_original, image_element):

  altura_1, w_1, channels_1 = image_original.shape
  height_2, w_2, channels_2 = image_element.shape

  partial_sum_1 = float(np.sum(image_original))
  average_1 = partial_sum_1 / (height_1 * w_1)
  partial_sum_2 = float(np.sum(image_element))
  average_2 = partial_sum_2 / (height_2 * w_2)

  # Normalized Cross Correlation

  top_equation = np.sum((imagem_original - average_1) * (imagem_elemento - average_2))
  e1 = np.sum((image_original - average_1)**2)
  e2 = np.sum((image_element - average_2)**2)
  result = (top_equation) / ((e1 * e2)**(1/2))
  return result
```

Comment: A formula without explanation of its assumptions and its variables and units is like saying *"a car at 50"* which could mean it is 50 years old, travelling at 50 miles per hour or 50 kilometres a week...

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html